# WCF DataServices Astoria Version 2 not returning results when called from Code

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have WCF DataService which works great when queried via directly through the browser. However, when run from Visual Studio 2010 where I'm trying to query and bind to a grid, it throws a DataServiceQueryException telling me "Resource Not Found" a 404 error. This is really bizarre. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ sv88erik, I don't understand. What do you mean "Finds VS all your functions?" ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you self hosting the service? When you test the service are you running it in the VS dev server?

My though is that the service may not actually be running when you try to add service reference.

Comment: The Service (.svc file) is in the main Client APP, but the service code resides in a class library. I thought about what you said but one cannot start up a class library along with the client when in VS

Comment: I don't know if I'm on the right track, but you can start more than 2 projects at once in VS. Once your first app is running, right click on the second project and select 'Debug > Start new instance"

Answer (score 0):

This is still having issues. The service is hosted in the client. Here is the full error:

[DataServiceClientException: 
    
        The resource cannot be found.
        
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }

```
<body bgcolor="white">

        <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

        <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

        <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
        <br><br>

        <b> Requested URL: </b>/TripReport.svc/OPRs<br><br>

        <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

        <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

        </font>

</body>
```

]
   System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.Execute() +475306
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) +137

[DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request.]
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) +396
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute() +77
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +13
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +315
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   TripReport.Controllers.GeneralControllers.GetDirectorates() in C:\Users\administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TripReport\Common\Controllers\GeneralControllers.cs:14
   TripReport.Controls.CreateTrip.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TripReport\Controls\CreateTrip.ascx.cs:16
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207